# slider on gallery on product page

Tags: magento2, gallery, fotorama-slider

I am trying in product/detail page to have all images in the gallery there with no slide to hide some of them, but it seems no possible in no option for view.xml.

I can create from scratch gallery.phtml of course but I would like to use what already exist in terms of zoom and responsiveness, keeping the gallery with dots on for the mobile